# How to make sure that iPhone app can NOT look for internet or wifi connection?

Tags: iphone, html, ios5

I've a client policy (hospitals) that app can **NOT** look for internet or wifi connection for safety reason.

I'm using HTML5 and jQuery. I'll have jQuery on local folder.

Is there a code that **suppress** (or prevent)  the iPhone or app to look for internet or wifi connection?

Is there a way that app user can send feedback from app when iPhone is turned on, I assume outside Hospital grounds?

Comment: do you want to check connection available or not?

Comment: No connection are required even if its available. It could interfere hospital equipments. Is there a way to prevent or stop iPhone to look for internet or wifi connection for this APP I'm creating?

Comment: It will look for operator/wifi network regardless of the app needs until the Airplane mode is on.

Comment: The only way I know to turn off an iPhone's WiFi is by going into Settings and turning off WiFi/setting it into airplane mode. I'm pretty sure regular apps have no access to this setting.

Comment: Its simple. Don't call any service that requires internet. Then your app will not check for internet.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking is even possible. First, I don't know how much hardware information could be accessed using html5 on a iOS environment (I believe apple sandbox it somewhat). Second, even if you get the suppress internet from your app, users could still connect to the internet from other app, thereby disrupting hospital equipments. A solution I can think of top of my head is to use some external equipment that can block cell use within certain areas. But who knows I maybe wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Application never automatically checks for internet connection availability.
App will check for internet availability only when **WE** (the developers) forces the app to execute a code which requires internet connection forcing it to check for internet connectivity.

In simple words
If you create an app that displays a label with text "Hello World on it.
This will never require an internet so it will not check for internet.

**Alternate way is to ask user to turn of wifi and data usage from Setting**